# Alertify for OnClick Event of Button

Tags: javascript, alertify

I'm trying to display a message that the user has clicked Delete button when he/she clicks on it. This is what I'm doing:

```
<script>
    $('#button_del').on('click',function(e){
        alertify.error('You have clicked on Delete!');
    });
</script>
```

But no message appears when I click on the button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your console. This could be many things. Handler is attached before DOM loads, #button_del doesn't exist, alertify is not defined, etc, etc...

Comment: Can you please give feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are only four possibilities here:

1. You don't load your libraries correctly: jQuery and alertify.
2. There is no element with the `button_del` ID, or there are markup errors involving it.
3. You're not actually clicking `#button_del`.

**4. the most likely one**:

You need to attach the click handler when the document is loaded, otherwise `#button_del` is *probably* not available/loaded yet!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button_del').on('click',function(e){
        alertify.error('You have clicked on Delete!');
    });
});
```

Even if the first three conditions are met, you'd still have to change this.

Comment: I've checked all 4 possibilities that you listed. Made the change you suggested as well. Still doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: @NoN01 can you check the developer console (try to press F12) and see if you get any errors?